# Three balls/eclipse appearing on my pc screen, how to remove them?

Tags: 18.04, mouse

The eclipse on screen is affect the mouse functionality and also tracking the mouse directions. It just showed up when I was using my keyboard and mouse.

**Note** VS Code, Rhythmbox, Files and Android Emulator programes were active during the period this happened.

How do I remove this? Thank you Posted with Love.

Screenshot for the eclipse
[image: Screenshot for the eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

Check your running Services/Programs (by searching in settings)which is related to the stuff which you were doing and stop it.